# Return columns when using Dynamic Sql - MVC

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

In my project, i want to search input values and i think i should create a SP using dynamic Sql. When i call this SP in MVC, it return "int".I want it return columns as ProductName,ProductCat ... . Example :

```
create SearchProduct
(@ProductId int =null,@ProductName nvarchar(50) = null,@ProductCatId int = null,.......)
as
declaredeclare @SqlStr nvarchar(max)
declare @ParamList nvarchar(2000)

set @SqlStr ='select p.ProductId,p.ProductName,p.ProductCatName,p.From,p.To  from Product p where (1=1)'
-- p.from , p. to is warranty period

if @ProductName is not null
set @SqlStr = 'and p.ProductName like ''%' +@ProductName + '%'' )'
......
set @ParamList ='@ProductId2,@ProductName2,@ProductCat2,....'
execute sp_executesql @sqlStr,@ParamList,@ProductId,@ProductName,@ProductCat,....
```

In MVC i call SP as :

```
var temp = db.SearchProduct(ProductId,ProductName,ProductCat,....)

// in here, var temp = int temp.
```